# Help to Refactor PHP Flip Image Code to smallest size as possible

Tags: php

I have written this PHP function which will flip an image (horizontally, like looking in a mirror). It reads the file, flips it, and writes it to a new filed called filename"_flipped".ext. I would like to refactor this to the smallest possible size, but maintaining human readability.

Here is the function:

```
function flip_image($filepath)
{
    if(file_exists($filepath)):

        //Array ( [dirname] => images 
        //        [basename] => pig.png 
        //        [extension] => png 
        //        [filename] => pig 
        //        [filesize] => 72 )
        $file = $this->get_file_info($filepath); // Returns above array

        // Is it allowed in our extensions array
        if(in_array($file['extension'], $this->allowed_exts)):

            // Reference our Image for the correct extension
            switch ($file['extension']) {
                case 'png':
                    $img = imagecreatefrompng($filepath);
                    break;
                case 'gif':
                    $img = imagecreatefromgif($filepath);
                    break;
                default: // Has to be JPG, or JPEG
                    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filepath);
                    break;
            }

            // Now we have our image...
            // Image Width & Height
            $size_x = imagesx($img);
            $size_y = imagesy($img);

            // Create Temp Image
            $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($size_x, $size_y);

            // Define a colour as transparant, allocate the colour, resample it
            imagecolortransparent($temp, imagecolorallocate($temp, 0, 0, 0));
            imagealphablending($temp, false);
            imagesavealpha($temp, true);

            $x = imagecopyresampled($temp, $img, 0, 0, ($size_x-1), 0, $size_x, $size_y, 0-$size_x, $size_y);
            if ($x) {
                $img = $temp;
            }
            else {
                die('Unable to flip image');
            }

            $writepath = $file['dirname'] . "/" . $file['filename'] . "_flipped" . ".";
            // Write our file
            switch ($file['extension']) {
                case 'png':
                    imagepng($img, $writepath.$file['extension']);
                    break;
                case 'gif':
                    imagegif($img, $writepath.$file['extension']);
                    break;
                default: // Has to be PNG
                    imagejpeg($img, $writepath.$file['extension']);
                    break;
            }
            $flipped_path = $writepath.$file['extension'];
            imagedestroy($img);
            return $flipped_path;
        else:
            echo 'Incorrect File Type, Not an Image, .png .gif, jpeg. jpeg Only.';
            return false;
        endif;
    else:
        echo 'No Such file found, Check the file path';
        return false;
    endif;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use call_user_func to check the extension only once. Something like this (I haven't got the time even to read the code now)

```
function flip_image($filepath)
{
if(file_exists($filepath)):

    //Array ( [dirname] => images 
    //        [basename] => pig.png 
    //        [extension] => png 
    //        [filename] => pig 
    //        [filesize] => 72 )
    $file = $this->get_file_info($filepath); // Returns above array

    // Is it allowed in our extensions array
    if(in_array($file['extension'], $this->allowed_exts)):
         // Reference our Image for the correct extension
        $outfile = $file['dirname'] . "/" . $file['filename'] . "_flipped" . "." . $file['extension'];
        switch ($file['extension']) {
            case 'png':
                return flip_image_in($filepath, $outfile, 'imagecreatefrompng', 'imagepng');
            case 'gif':
                return flip_image_in($filepath, $outfile, 'imagecreatefromgif', 'imagegif');
            default: // Has to be JPG, or JPEG
                return flip_image_in($filepath, $outfile, 'imagecreatefromjpeg', 'imagejpeg');
        }
    else:
        echo 'Incorrect File Type, Not an Image, .png .gif, jpeg. jpeg Only.';
        return false;
    endif;
else:
    echo 'No Such file found, Check the file path';
    return false;
endif;

}

function flip_image_in($inpath, $outfile, $create_function, $write_function)
{
        $img = call_user_func($create_function, $inpath);

        // Now we have our image...
        // Image Width & Height
        $size_x = imagesx($img);
        $size_y = imagesy($img);

        // Create Temp Image
        $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($size_x, $size_y);

        // Define a colour as transparant, allocate the colour, resample it
        imagecolortransparent($temp, imagecolorallocate($temp, 0, 0, 0));
        imagealphablending($temp, false);
        imagesavealpha($temp, true);

        $x = imagecopyresampled($temp, $img, 0, 0, ($size_x-1), 0, $size_x, $size_y, 0-$size_x, $size_y);
        if ($x) {
            $img = $temp;
        }
        else {
            die('Unable to flip image');
        }

        call_user_func($write_function, $img, $outfile);
        imagedestroy($img);
        return $outfile;
}
```